# Creating histogram of different sets

Tags: python

I am analyzing ratings for a certain product, and I want to create a histogram that includes the frequency of each rating out of 5 stars. For instance, I know that 2000 people said the product was 5 stars, and 400 said it was 4, etc. and I want to show that on a histogram.

I have five int values titled 'five,' 'four,' 'three,' etc.

How can I put these in a histogram, showing the number of 5-rated reviews compared to other rated reviews? Super new to python, as you might have guessed.

Edit: I took this data from a .tsv file, which has five columns. 'rating' is one of the five columns. I know numpy and matplotlib, I just need a little help coding multiple ints on a histogram, I guess.

Edit: here is my full code

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange,array,ones
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.genfromtxt("amazon_alexa 2.tsv", delimiter = '\t', 
       skip_header = 1, dtype=str, encoding = 'UTF-8')


rating = data[0:,0] #first column
date = data[:,1] #second column
alexa_type = data[:,2] #third column
comment = data[:,3] #fourth column

rating_ = []
for r in rating:
    r = int(r)
    rating_.append(r)

five = 0
four = 0
three = 0
two = 0
one = 0


for r in rating_:
    if (r == 5):
        five = five + 1
    if (r == 4):
        four = four + 1
    if (r == 3):
        three = three + 1
    if (r == 2):
        two = two + 1
    if (r == 1):
        one = one + 1
```

and it returns this:

```
Five Counter: 2286
Four Counter: 455
Three Counter: 152
Two Counter: 96
One Counter: 161
```

which I want to make into a histogram

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Have you identified any libraries you might use for this?

Comment: Can you show a sample of `rating` data and an idea of output??

Answer (score 1):

Using the `matplotlib` library allows you to plot directly from your data. A quick and dirty example:

```
import random

from matplotlib import pyplot as plot

numbers = [random.randint(1, 5) for i in range(0, 100)]
plot.hist(numbers)
plot.show()
```

Results in a histogram like:

[image: sample_histogram]

Axis modification and things like that are possible with some messing around with the `plot` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can store into a dict, then:

```
ratings = {5: 2286, 4: 455, 3: 152, 2: 96, 1: 161}

tot = sum([ x for k, x in ratings.items()])
limit = 50
normalized = []
for x in ratings:
  normalized.append( ( x, int(limit*(ratings[x]/tot)) ) )

for k, v in normalized:
  print(str(k) + ': ' + '*'*v)
```

`normalized` looks like this and you can build it directly from your code, without any dictionary:

```
[(5, 36), (4, 7), (3, 2), (2, 1), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: I got a type error for the line:for k, v in reversed(ratings.items()):

TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not reversible

Comment: @Aqua Wells, please, check now